# Command prompt output to be printed on swing panel itself.

Tags: java, swing, networking

Actually I had created a swing panel that takes input from user such as sourceno, destinationno, ttl and based on that data, I will apply my purely random propagation algorithm (PRP) to find out routing nodes traversed in network. Below code (PRP.java) will print the routing nodes traversed, on command prompt upon pressing submit button in swing panel.

I need to modify the code in such a way that upon pressing the submit button the resultant traversed route should be printed on a textbox in the same panel below the submit button but not on command prompt

Please suggest modified code.....

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PRP extends JFrame
{


JTextField srcno;
JTextField destno;
JTextField ttl;
JTextField datapayload;
JLabel srcnode;
JLabel destnode;
JLabel TTL;
JLabel Datapayload;
JButton submit;
JTextArea textFieldName;


  public PRP()
  {

    PRPLayout customLayout = new PRPLayout();

    getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    getContentPane().setLayout(customLayout);

    srcnode = new JLabel("Enter source node:");
    getContentPane().add(srcnode);

    srcno = new JTextField("number");
    getContentPane().add(srcno);

    destnode = new JLabel("Enter destination node:");
    getContentPane().add(destnode);

    destno = new JTextField("number");
    getContentPane().add(destno);

    TTL = new JLabel("Enter TTL:");
    getContentPane().add(TTL);

    ttl = new JTextField("number");
    getContentPane().add(ttl);

     Datapayload = new JLabel("Enter DataPayload:");
    getContentPane().add(Datapayload);

    datapayload = new JTextField("abcd...");
    getContentPane().add(datapayload);

    submit = new JButton("submit");
    getContentPane().add(submit);

    textFieldName = new JTextArea("PRP ROUTING:",80,10);
    textFieldName.setEditable( false );
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textFieldName) ;
    scroll.setBounds( 10, 60, 225, 150 );
    getContentPane().add( scroll );

    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                         {
                                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                            {

                                              String[]  prpdata = new String[3];
                                              prpdata[0]=srcno.getText();
                                              prpdata[1]=destno.getText();
                                              prpdata[2]=ttl.getText();
                                              try{ 
                                              PRP pr = new PRP();
                                              pr.PRPRoute(prpdata); }
                                              catch(Exception ez){ textFieldName.append("exception in caller method"); }


                                             }
                                           });

    setSize(getPreferredSize());

    }

    public void PRPRoute(String argus[]) throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
    {

     String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
     String u="proj";
     String p="bade";
     String src=argus[0];
     String dest=argus[1];
     int ttl=Integer.parseInt(argus[2]);
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,u,p);
     if(con==null)
     {
       textFieldName.append("not connected to oracle");
       return;
      }

     textFieldName.append("connected to oracle");

     String query= "select distinct RFrom,RTo from router where RFrom='"+src+"'"+"or "+ "RTo='"+src+"'";

     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);

     ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

     int j=-1;

     String[]  randata = new String[30];
     textFieldName.append( "\n\t"+"Neighbors of " + src+"::");  

     while( rs.next() )
     {  
       j++;
       for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++)
      {

        String ss=rs.getString( i );
        if(!(ss.equals(src)))
        {
           textFieldName.append( "\t" + ss );
           randata[j]=ss ;  
        }
      }

      textFieldName.append( "\n\n" );   
     }
     int k=0;
     textFieldName.append("\n"+"Checking for 1-hop neighbours. . . .");

     for(int i=0;i<=j;i++)
     {
        if(randata[i].equals(dest))
        textFieldName.append("1-hop neighbour found");
        textFieldName.append( "\t" + "Routing followed:"+src+"--->" +randata[i]);
        textFieldName.append("\n\t successfully routed!");
        k=i;
        break;
      }
   }

   if(!(randata[k].equals(dest)))
   {
    textFieldName.append("Choosen dispersive PRP strategy!!!");
    textFieldName.append( "\t" + "Routing followed:"+src+"--->" );
    Random r=new Random();
    if(ttl<=0) { 
              textFieldName.append("MINHOP ROUTING STARTED");

           }
     else {
          ttl--;
          String next=randata[r.nextInt(j)];
          textFieldName.append(next);
          if(next.equals(dest)) { textFieldName.append("\n\t successfully routed!"); }
          else{
               String[] indata = new String[3];
               indata[0]=next;
               indata[1]=dest;
               indata[2]=Integer.toString(ttl);
               try{ PRPRouteout pr=new PRPRouteout(indata); }
               catch(Exception ezl){ textFieldName.append("exception in PRPRouteut caller method"); }


             }
         }
     }


    }




 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    PRP window = new PRP();

    window.setTitle("PRP");
    window.pack();
    window.show();
 }
}

class PRPLayout implements LayoutManager
{
  public PRPLayout() {  }
  public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {   }
  public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {  }
  public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent)
 {
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
    dim.width = 320 + insets.left + insets.right;
    dim.height = 240 + insets.top + insets.bottom;
     return dim;
 }

 public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent)
 {
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
    return dim;
 }
 public void layoutContainer(Container parent) 
 {
    Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
    Component c;
    c = parent.getComponent(0);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+90,insets.top+8,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(1);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+230,insets.top+8,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(2);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+90,insets.top+40,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(3);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+230,insets.top+40,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(4);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+90,insets.top+72,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(5);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+230,insets.top+72,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(6);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+90,insets.top+112,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(7);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+230,insets.top+112,172,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(8);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+230,insets.top+152,142,26);}
    c = parent.getComponent(9);
    if (c.isVisible()) {c.setBounds(insets.left+90,insets.top+200,472,268);}
 }
}
```

Comment: It is a good question but example is too long.

Comment: I cannot read your code due to its crazy formatting. Consider fixing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly then Try this:

Use `textFieldName.setText();` instead of `System.out.println();`

Comment: I had changed my code by replacing System.out.println(); with textFieldName.append(); ...there are no errors but textearea is just blank without any result.... @bhushan

Comment: @user2224922 `JTextField jtf = new JTextField(); jtf.setText("Bhushan");` this is what needs to be done, first create a textfield object, then use `setText()` method to set Text in textfield

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about your code. But i know the way which we can use the Ping or trace route... and take the result into .txt file. Write your command like that 
ping 192.168.1.1 -t > filename.txt

mind if your use this too 
To delay between pings and record the time of each you can do some scripting.

@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
time /T
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 4 >> filename.txt
ping yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -n 4 >> filename.txt
sleep -m 3000
GOTO LOOPSTART

it will create a File in root directory. and it will print all the results untill your exit the command.